# Fail configure DPDK in OVS:DPDK support not built

Tags: openvswitch, dpdk

I am installing DPDK in Open vSwitch (OVS). 
https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/INSTALL.DPDK.md

The problem is when I ran 2 commands like this.

```
export DB_SOCK=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock
sudo ovs-vswitchd --dpdk -c 0x1 -n 4 -- unix:$DB_SOCK --pidfile --detach
```

I got error:

> ovs-vswitchd: DPDK support not built into this copy of Open vSwitch.

Could anyone please explain to me how to fix this pronlem.
Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile OVS against DPDK with DPDK support enabled (`--with-dpdk`):

`export DPDK_BUILD=$DPDK_DIR/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/
./configure --with-dpdk=$DPDK_BUILD
make
make install`